# Why the image imported as plane is not transparent?

Tags: image, transparency

I imported the png image with alpha channel as plane, but it doesn't have transparency to it.
Why is that?
Thank you in advance!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, are you sure that your image is transparent? the grid seems to be part of the image, could you please share your original image?

Comment: Yep, maybe it was the image. However I changed it to another one and still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure "Use Alpha" is checked when importing Image as Plane. If you do this, and the image is actually transparent, it will take care of it automatically

Comment: I did exactly that, but still couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: Neither image you've uploaded has a transparent background, the grid is baked into both

Comment: Oops. Sorry... I'll try it again with the other image

Comment: Yeah it works now. Thanks a lot